# CSS Filter not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I am trying CSS filter but it does not work in my Firefox (15.0) browser.

HTML:

```
<div class="google">
     <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.google{   
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/xDJzU/

Comment: Starting in Firefox 35 (Jan 2015), the vanilla "filter:" CSS property will do the trick. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 50, accepted):

GrayScale has limitations to work in firefox using a -moz-filter.

To get it working use the below snippet:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xDJzU/7/)

Comment: that works, but is it the only syntax to make it work? Doesn't the newer FF versions have simple syntax ?

Comment: @user1251698: I dont think so but you can have  a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter

Comment: FWIW, [here is a losy invert filter version of this answer.](http://jsfiddle.net/4nLGG/)

Comment: How to unset the grayscale for firefox 3.5?

Answer (score 13):

Rewrite your css code with this one, assuming that you're trying to achieve a grayscale image:

```
.google{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}
​
```

**Updated jsfiddle:** [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xDJzU/8/)

Comment: Have you tested your jsfiddle link it in your Firefox? In my browser the image totally disappeared. If i remove `filter:url(resources...` line, it will appear but no effect.

Comment: sorry, now it should work. i've updated the link in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the problem that in Firefox 39.0 images completely dissappeared when I used

```
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
```

What solved it for me was to add "filter: grayscale(1)" - just like that:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
filter: grayscale(1); /* Firefox 39 (and above? Don´t know) */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
```

This made it work for me. Don't know what about IE 10+ though, haven't testet it

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you 100%.

```
.google{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); 
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%)
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy aspirinemaga's answer and strip the comments?

Comment: @BoltClock: Actually mine and same for aspirinemaga's answer. Bad part of SO.

Comment: no i didnt.I have search for this question on google and find result from here http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html if answer is same then what can i do ? i dont think so u people write this by your own ? did you ?

Comment: how to roll back filter effect suppose on hover?