# How to use Compass filter mixin?

Tags: css, compass-sass, mixins

I'm trying to use filter mixin this way in SCSS:

```
a {
  @include filter(grayscale(100%));
}
```

But when I compile, I got this error:

```
Undefined mixin 'filter'.
```

I'm using the latest version of this Gem with Rails framework.

http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/filter/

Comment: Did you remember to import the file where the mixin is defined?  `@import "compass/css3/filter"`

Comment: @cimmanon Yep! Other mixins work well... :)

Answer (score 22):

**SASS Example**

```
@import 'compass/css3/filter'

.filtered
  @include filter(grayscale(50%))
  @include filter(blur(2px))
```

Comment: Attention: not all/possibly any firefox supports grayscale filters. (Status: June 2014) For a firefox grayscale fallback: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173130/css-filter-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: To actually apply multiple filters you will have to pass them all in one `@include filter()`.  Using two @includes will produce multiple filter properties and the last one included used will override any earlier ones.

Answer (score 10):

You need to import compass filter first.

To use multiple filters put all inside filter() without commas

```
@import 'compass/css3/filter'

// multiple calls like this:
.filtered {
    @include filter(blur(4px) brightness(1.3) saturate(1.5));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Compass documentation](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/filter/) this file can be imported using: `@import "compass/css3/filter"` at the top of sass file.

And then in sass file you can use it as

```
filter($filter-1, $filter-2, $filter-3, $filter-4, $filter-5, $filter-6, $filter-7, $filter-8, $filter-9, $filter-10)
```