# Jquery Trigger Working Chrome, IE but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently my code will trigger in chrome, and IE but in firefox nothing.. I added console.log and boom in FireFox the code gets there, so isn't the CSS being added?

```
jQuery("#eigth").waypoint(function(direction) {
    console.log('got here');
    jQuery("#globe").css({'filter:' : 'none', '-webkit-filter' : 'grayscale(0%)'});
});
```

Comment: `-moz-filter`?? `-webkit` webkit browsers (so no Firefox). And `filter` is for IE? (correct me if i'm wrong). So you need to add a CSS for Firefox.#

Comment: `webkit-filter` targets Webkit based browsers - for Firefox, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173130/css-filter-not-working-in-firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code

```
jQuery("#eigth").waypoint(function(direction) {
    console.log('got here');
    jQuery("#globe").css({'filter:' : 'none', '-webkit-filter' : 'grayscale(0%)'});
});
```

Syntax error (:)

```
{'filter' : 'none' instead of {'filter:' : 'none'
```

Comment: You god. Enough said :)