# Javascript busted in only Firefox, fine in other browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, browser

I've nearly finished my new [website](http://www.alinewbury.com)

but a few elements (primarily JavaScript and css) don't work in Firefox.

I am afraid to go change too much code around because everything looks a-okay in other browsers (safari, chrome, opera, etc.) for some reason my jQuery/JavaScript just seems busted in Firefox.

Can someone assist me in cleaning the bugs, because I simply cannot find them?

Comment: post your code that having the issue...

Comment: ..and do you have a more specific problem than 'just seems busted'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have so many troubles that I don't even know where to begin with.

First: Fonts mismatch. Tested on Mozilla 31.0 and Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Check this out.

Second: where you have -webkit- prefix you also need prefixes for mozilla (-moz-), opera (-o-) and IE (-ms-). Otherwise it will work only in Safari/Chrome.

Also, specifically for the filters take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173130/css-filter-not-working-in-firefox) (mozilla has issues with filters.)

Third: You have files that are NOT found. As in css files.

Forth: Check your modernizr. It's somewhat outdated. Can be a source of issues.

Fifth: Your css is not executing well (at all), check it for errors.

Sixth: css Hyphens require prefix (-webkit-, -moz- and etc. It's probable that this breaks your css and your site)

PS: Still looking for more mistakes.

### EDIT:

[Explanation](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm) on prefixes.

Fonts:

They appear different, but that can be because of the size. Also I see it all in lower case. Probably the least of your problems and it will probably be resolved upon fixing the rest.

CSS:

The file `col.css` is included, but not found on the site.

Modernizr:

Yoiur version is Modernizr 2.5.3. The current newest version is 2.8.3. For reference Modernizr 2.6 came out in 2012. You can check their [site](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: I'm pretty new to all of this so I just need some clarification on what you're saying, I don't really understand half of what you're trying to help me with. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @user3417687 Which part is it that you don't understand? I'll edit my answer accordingly to provide more info.

Comment: Most of it, I don't understand that my fonts have mismatched, and that my css files cannot be found. And how do I check my moderniser is outdated? I apologise, I'm really new to this

Comment: @user3417687 I added explanations, sorry for the delay.